# What titles apply to non-monastic/lay Buddhists? (upasaka/upasika savaka/sravaka)

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, pali-language, sangha, labeling

Labels are illusions like all conditioned phenomena, but I have an attachment to taxonomy and being able to describe myself accurately. I'm working on that, but in the meantime, I thought this would be a good question for the stack.

**How best can people describe themselves in the hierarchy/ecology of believers if they aren't living the monastic life of the Bhikkhu/Bhikkhuṇī (monk/nun), but still consider themselves as living a life driven by the dhamma?**

I personally identify as Theravada/Pali canon/early Bhuddism, but an answer specifying Mahayana/Vajrayana titles is also welcome!

Ideally I'd like Pali words and their best English equivalents, but obviously including Sanskrit versions too would be polite (^_^)

BONUS POINTS: My gender is non-binary (genderqueer/agender) and thus I really need a title that can apply to me without need to specify gender. If I ever become a monastic I will really have my work cut out for me and/or a need to compromise, but for any non-monastics with non-binary gender, which titles are functional for us?

Comment: Welcome and Bienvenue to the site. You may like to read that this site has a few *non-standard* policies, which are summarised and indexed [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2108/254).

Comment: Thanks Chris. Seems like my question and answer are safe but please let me know if I can do better :)

Comment: What is meant by "non-binary gender", physical or just mental confused?

Comment: Samana here is the relevant Wikipedia article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genderqueer 

So that you know, "mental confused" as a description of transgender people is not acceptable and considered very rude. 

The question I believe you are trying to ask is whether I am intersex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex) or not, to which my answer is that it isn't relevant because my gender identity is what is important, not my genitalia.

Comment: People are welcome to discuss gender in [one of the chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism) or elsewhere.

Comment: You might find https://discourse.suttacentral.net/ interesting, since they make their livelihoods on gender issues. As for the rest, no answer can be given to one not able to be straight and very pride. As for eventually able to become monk, very important and [relevant](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/vin/mv/mv01/mv.01.54.khem_en.html). While mental confusing could be healed stronger manifestations can not.

Comment: @SamanaJohann thank you for the link to suttacentral, I found compassionate consideration of trans people’s role in Buddhism quickly there. I guess you are referring to the fact that I am effectively identifying as a pandaka which seems about right in fact (though it can apply both for psychological and physiological reasons it seems). To go forth I would need to find a monastic order reformist enough to welcome pandakas or I wouldn’t want to join.

Comment: I am a  non-binary bi-romantic asexual. I used a male title when I ordained. Because the very girlish person, such as person who go around to fuck with the other male monastic members in vinaya-pitaka, was denied to  ordain in buddhism. They can be just a lay. In commentary, some kind of girlish people can ordain but some can not. It  depend on their physical body.

http://84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=04&A=3481&eng=suttacentral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer my own question, with **Theravada** emphasis, there are two main categories that apply to non-monastics:

*TODO:* Add "uninstructed worldling" as an option for fun. Research "Bhauddhaya"

#### Upāsaka (masculine) or Upāsikā (feminine)

- Translates to "attendant" and means "devout follower". ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up%C4%81saka_and_Up%C4%81sik%C4%81))
- Specifically refers to people who are **not** part of a monastic order.

#### Śrāvaka (Sanskrit) / [Sāvaka](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=20&A=648&w=s%C4%81vak%C4%81na%E1%B9%83%20bhikkh%C5%ABna%E1%B9%83) (Pali) : Masculine or Śrāvikā (Sanskrit) / [Sāvikā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=20&A=660&w=s%C4%81vik%C4%81na%E1%B9%83%20bhikkhun%C4%ABna%E1%B9%83) (Pali) : Feminine

- Translates to "hearer" and means "disciple" ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ar%C4%81vaka))
- Transcends monastic-lay divisions and can refer to anyone from the following "four assemblies":

  - bhikkhus ("monks")
  - bhikkuṇīs ("nuns")
  - upāsakas and upāsikā (laypersons)
- **Does not describe Mahāyāna Buddhists**: As noted in the  ["Mahāyāna view" section of the Savaka wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ar%C4%81vaka#Mah%C4%81y%C4%81na_view), the word "śrāvakas" has a very precise connotation when used in the Mahāyāna context, which implies that "śrāvaka" means someone "set on their own liberation, and cultivating detachment in order to attain liberation". I.e. Theravada Buddhists seeking nibbana, in contrast to Mahāyāna Buddhists following the Bodhisattva path to "liberation of all beings".

#### Saddhānusārī

- Translates to "faith follower"
- Mentioned in [Cakkhu Sutta: The Eye](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.001.than.html) ([Pali](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sltp/SN_III_utf8.html#pts.225))

  > Monks, the eye is inconstant, changeable, alterable. The ear... The nose... The tongue... The body... The mind is inconstant, changeable, alterable.
  >
  > "One who has conviction & belief that these phenomena are this way is called a faith-follower: one who has entered the orderliness of rightness, entered the plane of people of integrity, transcended the plane of the run-of-the-mill. He is incapable of doing any deed by which he might be reborn in hell, in the animal womb, or in the realm of hungry shades. He is incapable of passing away until he has realized the fruit of stream-entry."
- Based on this, it seems to imply a very high minimum level of attainment to qualify, as you would have to be very precisely a sotapanna-magga (on the path to stream entry) with a guarantee of becomming sotapanna-phala (accomplishing stream entry) within your current lifetime.
- Strikes me as a title that few would ever want to apply to themselves, and essentially equivalent to [sotapanna-magga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sot%C4%81panna#Attainment), though I am not clear yet on whether sotapanna-magga explicitly means you will accomplish stream entry in the current life or not.

#### Conclusion: Savaka describes all Theravada Buddhists

So it seems, **the best, most generic term that applies to any non-Mahāyāna Buddhist, regardless of gender or role is Savaka**, a disciple of Buddha with unspecified gender but also unspecified role as monastic or lay person.

*If you have male or female gender*, you would be both a **Savaka** and a **Upāsaka** or **Upāsikā**.

*If you are part of a monastic order* then you are also a **Bhikkhu** or **Bhikkuṇī**

*If you can lay claim to any spiritual attainments* then you can *also* use a variety of words to describe these achievements. These include **Saddhānusārī**, and of course the [Four stages of enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_enlightenment), for example the most accessible stage, [**Sotapanna**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sot%C4%81panna).

Comment: Savaka is broadly used to refer to thos well-following, e.g. Noble ones in southern/early Traditions, denoting those beyond "just" attending, "children of the Sakyan"

Comment: That means if calling your self Savaka is seen as claiming an attainment broadly, as for SEAsian communities. They bow daily to the Savaka-Sangha.

Comment: It makes sense they bow down to the savaka sangha because that includes both the lay and monastic communities.

Comment: In terms of "savaka" meaning "noble follower" that seems more linked with "ariyasāvaka" as mentioned in the savaka wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ar%C4%81vaka#Ariyas%C4%81vaka

It seems there's precedent for "savaka", used on it's own, including those merely intending to be on the path (e.g. sotāpatti-magga)

Comment: Also, sravaka explicitly identifies the person as non-mahayana follower. I believe that's what you want, so we are fine here.

Comment: Andrei: That's an interesting point. Is that because of the meaning that Savaka includes the concept of seeking nibbana, rather than being a Bodhisattva?

Comment: There's [*a* text](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/18605/254) (I don't know how many others) where "the Hearer family" is distinguished from "the Mahayana family" -- I'm not sure why -- I think the three distinguishing "marks" stated there are "*afraid* of samsara" and "*yearning* for nibbana" and "little interest in benefiting sentient beings".

Comment: Okay, yeah, thanks @ChrisW, I read this in the [Savaka wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ar%C4%81vaka#Mah%C4%81y%C4%81na_view) ("Mahāyāna view" section). So it seems that it's the same word, which is pretty generic, but for Mahāyāna followers, it's a kind of "slur" against Theravada followers, associated with the doctrinal disagreements, rather than with it's original meaning.

Comment: I've updated the Savaka section with a summary of what seems to be the case with Mahāyāna views on śrāvaka. If anyone sees a problem with it let  me know. I've also added Saddhānusārī from Dean A's answer with some context about why I don't think it's a good fit for me or most people.

Comment: @jerclarke If it *is* (or was) a "slur against", IMO it's about "Hinayana" not "Theravada".

Comment: I am not sure that I may be read your last paragraph correctly. IMO, your conclusion should be: sāvaka-male=(bhikkhu-male-monastic + upāsaka-male-lay) and sāvikā-female= (bhikkunī-female-monastic + upāsikā-female-lay). When they are saddhānusārī ariya, they will be ariya-sāvaka/ariya-sāvikā.

Comment: @Bonn I never found a reference to the savaka/savika gender divide, so I assume there isn't one. Do you have a reference for that? It seems "hearer" doesn't mention gender.

Comment: My point in the final paragraph was just that saddhānusārī only applies to those with accomplishments, and so isn't usually a good answer to my question about lay people.

Comment: Ok, I will edit your post with pāli reference. You can read my answer over there. And after edit, I will copy to my blog. So, just feel free to accept or to deny my edition.

Comment: In my added pali link, you can found "sāvakānaṃ  bhikkhūnaṃ" and "sāvikānaṃ  bhikkhunīnaṃ".

Answer (score 4):

you might get a few answers but here is my thought:

Śrāvaka (Sanskrit) or **Sāvaka** (Pali) means "hearer" or, more generally, or"disciple", or "one who sits near", "one who lend ears"

Gender neutral and describes all level of achievements.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote my own answer up with more detail, but yours is exactly right and the same conclusion I came to. Gonna keep editing mine hopefully and add more details :)

Comment: Come to think of it, savaka were also used for followers of other great 8 religions at Buddha's time too.   It doesn't give clear answer as what one listens to.  I'm a savaka but a savaka to whom?  Chris' answer might be a more direct hit.  Good luck.

Comment: I’d be a Buddha savaka presumably, just like I follow the Dhamma and that’s the right word, even though really I should specify “Buddha Dhamma” in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

There's [Saddhānusārī](http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/Saddh%C4%81nus%C4%81r%C4%AB) translated "faith follower".

And [Dhammānusārī](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dhammanusari) translated "follower of the law".

According to [SN 25.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.001.than.html) these appear to be on the road to stream entry.

Comment: Thanks these are interesting new answers! I’ll add them to my big answer as further options.