# I don't know pali or Sanskrit if anyone can have pdf of english Tipitaka

Tags: tipitaka

Can anyone please send me link to the pdf of line by line English translation of Tipitaka at least translation only.

Answer (score 3):

The Tipitaka, also known as the Pali Canon, is a very huge collection of text. The main religious text of other religions like the Bible, can easily fit into one hand as a book. Compared to this, the Tipitaka is very huge. It's more like a library shelf full of books.

The Tipitaka is organized into three "baskets", namely the Sutta Pitaka which mainly contains the discourses (suttas) of the Buddha and his chief disciples, the Vinaya Pitaka which contains rules for the monastic order, and the Abhidhamma Pitaka, which contains detailed analyses and summaries for advanced students.

I assume that you're a beginner. A beginner would mostly be interested in the Suttas. Even then, the amount of suttas are vast, and they are not arranged in a way that is friendly to beginners.

For beginners, I highly recommend the book "[In The Buddha's Words](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0861714911)" by [Bhikkhu Bodhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu_Bodhi). It is an anthology or selection of translated suttas from the Pali Canon. It is also thematically and systematically arranged. You can look at the Table of Contents on the Amazon page I linked. It is 512 pages long, which is quite alright. There was an online PDF version [here](http://www.pacificbuddha.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/In-the-Buddhas-Words.pdf), but that link doesn't work today.

Another option is to try "[Path to Freedom: A Self Guided Tour of the Buddha's Teachings](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/index.html)" by [Access to Insight](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/).

[This question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/471) on Buddhism.SE has suggested lists of suttas in an order or sequence that is suitable for beginners. They are also linked to the online English translations.

Yet another option is the book "[Early Buddhist Discourses](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/Early%20Buddhist%20Discourses_Holder.pdf)" by John J. Holder. [This](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/Early%20Buddhist%20Discourses_Holder.pdf) is in fact an online PDF copy. According to [the books's Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0872207927), it contains "twenty discourses from the Pali Canon--including those most essential to the study and teaching of early Buddhism - are provided in fresh translations, accompanied by introductions that highlight the main themes and set the ideas presented in the context of wider philosophical and religious issues."

The options above will give you nicely arranged content for your study.

If you just want to refer to particular suttas of the Tipitaka in English, please see [Sutta Central](https://suttacentral.net/) or [Access to Insight](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/).

For a classic introduction to the Buddha's teachings, I recommend the book "[What the Buddha Taught](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802130313)" by [Walpola Rahula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walpola_Rahula_Thero). You can find the PDF version [here](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/What%20the%20Buddha%20Taught_Rahula.pdf). There is also a very short collection of the suttas at the back of the book.

Answer (score 2):

The best site is Sutta Central. It has the translation in many languages:
https://suttacentral.net/

The next best is Access to insight:
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/index.html