# Who said "cease to do evil learn to do good purify the heart"?

Tags: reference-request

Who said this as a complete description of the Buddhist path

> Cease to do evil
>
> Learn to do good
>
> Purify the heart

I thought it was Bodhidharma but I can't find the exact reference for the quote. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [verse 183 of the Dhammapada](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=183).

Comment: I don't expect it's a "complete description".

Comment: "This is the teaching of *(all the)* Buddhas." - implies the obviousness of it to anyone who is awakened. How wonderful and how true.

Comment: The actual story I heard was a Chinese emperorer sends for a Buddhist teacher to explain the Buddhist path. The teacher just says "cease to do evil learn to do good purify the heart". The emperor is not pleased and says " but a child of 7 years old could understand that". The teacher replies "But an old man of 80 could fail to put it into practice".

Comment: @CrabBucket, here is that story just as you described it. Seems like a teaching story without any specific origins though. http://www.freebuddhistaudio.com/texts/read?num=048

Comment: It may sound simple, but many people don't know what evil really means and what causes evil. Even if you tell to get rid of craving, aversion and ignorance, people would still need to be taught what those really mean.